# Keep a tally based on input value - different "variables"?

Tags: python, variables

I have a code:

```
vote = raw_input("Enter who you vote for: ")
```

But what I need is for the raw_input() to "create" a variable, if something has been entered in the first time - for example:

```
>>>
Enter who you vote for: foo
>>> foo = 1
```

And if I then enter "foo" again, the foo count would go up by 1.

```
Enter who you vote for: foo
>>> foo += 1
```

This is most likely a simplistic presentation of it and the real deal is more complicated, but just to give the idea that I want.

Comment: See http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/dictionaries.html - *dictionaries* (aka a [Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)), not *variables* are the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
votes = defaultdict(int)
vote = raw_input("Enter who you vote for: ")
votes[vote] += 1
```

Comment: Ran into an issue here (which sort of might even be it's own question): if - for example - I set a limit of 5 votes before someone is declared the winner, how would I test if someone has gotten 5 votes (and there is multiple entries, let's say "foo" and "bar"?

Comment: @GotGaming_ Someone gets 5 votes first. Or the votes are only counted at the end and it's a tie. Or the first one to get any votes wins or..

Comment: @user2864740 Someone gets 5 votes first, but how would I test it if the vote counts are dependent on user input? If I wanted to test if a certain value (like "foo") got 5 votes I could do: `if votes["foo"] == 5`, but if the value is not certain, the I'm not sure :S

Comment: @GotGaming_ (after the increment) `if votes[vote] == 5: print "The winner is " + vote`?

Comment: @user2864740 That's not exactly how I want it, however I figured it out. I will post it as an answer because I feel like if there's anyone else needing help with something similar, they could use what I've thought up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figured out a maximum vote count using `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
votes = defaultdict(int)
vote = raw_input("Enter who you vote for: ")
votes[vote] += 1

voted = []                  ##create empty list for user inputted votes
voted.append(vote)          ##append what user inputs to the list

for name in voted:
    if votes[name] == 5:    ##maximum vote count is 5
        print 'The winner is '+name+'.'
```

This should be a pretty foolproof code as two names cannot possibly accumulate 5 votes at the same moment.

Answer (score -2):

I do like the `defaultdict` answer better, but simply following the concept of creating a variable you can use `exec`:

```
exec vote + ' = 1'
```

This executes a command `foo = 1` if `vote` is `"foo"`.
This is although **dangerous** and can hard to identify, have you already created a variable (you'd have to `try` accessing it and then catching an exception would mean it does not exist yet).

P.S. Yes, this is perverted. A bit :)

Comment: My son is named `votes = {'little bobby tables': 10 ** 6}; losers` :) -- xkcd.com/327

Comment: Exactly what I meant by "dangerous". The answer wasn't even close to being serious.

Comment: Yes I knew, bit rarely I can cite little Bobby tables, so I do it when I can ;)